# Is it possible top opt-out of INamingContainer if it's implemented by a superclass?

Tags: asp.net, templates, user-controls

The UserControl class inherits from TemplateControl which implements INamingContainer. Since this is ["only a marker interface"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx) I was wondering if it's possible to *opt-out* of the behavior that this interface brings with it.

I am developing a templated control based on a user control, and I want the controls inside the template to be accessible in the page without using `FindControl(id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible.